# Is it possible to create servers in PgAdmin 6.10

Tags: backend, amazon-rds, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am new to servers.
I have a RDS AWS server which i need to conect my PgAdmin.
But the problem is that i don't have option in Servers list to Create Server only a Server Group.
Does anyone know what should i do ?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently, pgAdmin has moved the server registration to "Register" menu as it does not actually create a server but registers it to pgAdmin.